# Linking to Boost in DLL file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost, dll

I've created a Win32 DLL application that links to the Boost Library.  It compiles, and all is well and good, except that if I create another application that references the DLL, it requires that that application link to Boost as well. If I don't link to Boost, I get a "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/utility.hpp': No such file or directory." Is there any way around this?  I'm a noob, so I feel that I may be missing something essential, but I haven't found anything in searching yet. Thanks!

Comment: That looks like a compilation error (or preprocessor error, even) not a *linking* error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Biffen said in the comments, that is a compilation error.  You project needs to be able to read the Boost header file(s) that your other project used, so you'll have to edit your project settings "additional include directories" so that the location of the Boost header files is accessible.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. When I add Boost as an additional include directory in the console application that's using the DLL it works fine.  My issue is that I want to be able to distribute this DLL. It seems cumbersome to require that the user have the Boost library as well. Just wondering if you have any ideas what the best workaround might be.

Comment: I don't believe the user will need to have the Boost library to run your console application (that uses your DLL).  I believe your issue was that your console application couldn't compile simply because it didn't have the needed declarations/definitions provided in the Boost headers.  Once your console application (*.exe) and DLL are built you should be able to take them to another machine that doesn't have the Boost library and they should work fine.  Have you tried this?

Comment: So I should have stated what my application was initially-- my DLL is meant to be an API for interfacing with a device through a serial port.  I created the console application to test out this functionality. So ideally I would like the DLL to be standalone.

Comment: Try refactoring your code so that the Boost headers are only included in your implementation (*.cpp) files.  This may require forward-declaring some of the Boost classes and only using pointers or references to those Boost classes in your class declarations.